# how to search string longer than stored in DB - SQL Server, PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, string

I have a question about aproach for searching strings longer then the one stored in DB.

For example: String stored in DB is "somestring". I need to mach it with changed string e.g. "somestringXY".

I have a DB with stored models but in the files I need to parse, strings are often modified.
What I can do is:

1. I can `SELECT * 'string' from Table` and then search needle via foreach and substr/preg_match.
2. I can also `SELECT * 'string' FROM Table` to array and then search via the `in_array` function.
3. I can also make a loop, cut last letter, make a select on DB and find match. If no match do loop again.

Let's say that there shouldn't be double matches so in DB there will not be strings (somestringXY, somestringX, somestring).

Maybe there are also other approaches? Of course Like in SQL is not helpful because searched string is longer then stored in DB.

Comment: Maybe you should go from the other end, start at `s`

Comment: What happens if you have both `some` and `somestring` in the database and you have `somestringXY` in your files? Is that `some` modified to append `stringXY` or is that `somestring` modified to append `XY` or do you need both ? Also, are you dealing with only appends or all types of modification?

Comment: Sql Server or MySQL? Include only the relevant tags

Comment: Juan Carlos Oropeza -> thank you, I have deleted inproper tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there exists a specific MySQL way of doing this, but I would go with this route:

```
$substrarray = array("'somestri'","'somestrin'", "'somestring'","'somestringX'","'somestringXY'");

$substrings = implode(",",$substrarray);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE string IN (".$substrings.")";
```

The problem of course is that this might bring you unwanted results, depending what you are looking for and how similar those strings are to eachother. But the pro is that it only does one call, instead of multiple when you check after every time you have deleted a letter.